# How to save datagridview columns with datas in sql server database

Tags: c#, sql

Scenario is.... I have to select a row in datagridview and save those datas to database.It can any number of columns present. how to achieve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good way to achieve this is to create XML string of all modified rows.

Than pass this string to Stored procedure.

In stored procedure use [OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276847(SQL.80).aspx) which allow you to update multiple rows easily.